# How to list non-default parameters in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to list non-default parameters in MySQL?

I am looking for something like `\dconfig+` from `postgresql`

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` -- for values of all ~500 possible settings.

Comment: @RickJames That shows all the values, including those that are using their compiled defaults. It does not say which ones are overridden by config options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use MySQL 8.0 to get this, but read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-variables-info-table.html

```
SELECT VI.VARIABLE_NAME, GV.VARIABLE_VALUE, VI.VARIABLE_SOURCE
FROM performance_schema.variables_info AS VI
   INNER JOIN performance_schema.global_variables AS GV
   USING(VARIABLE_NAME)
WHERE VI.VARIABLE_SOURCE <> 'COMPILED'
ORDER BY VARIABLE_NAME;
```

If you're not on MySQL 8.0 yet, you should upgrade. MySQL 5.x is out of support by the end of October 2023.

Comment: Thanks! no way to do it in 5.7? mayber other view?

Comment: The `variables_info` table is a new feature in MySQL 8.0. It is not implemented in MySQL 5.7, and there is no other solution besides you eyeballing your `my.cnf` file to see which variables are set.